# Setting Nested TextView Text

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I've created a layout for a button format I use multiple times. The button format has a TextView and an ImageView. With the way I'm including this layout in my main activity, I don't think I'm able to change the text of the inner TextView dynamically in Java or in the XML. Is there a different way I can do this such that I can set the text of the inner TextView?

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/settingslayout">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="CHANGE ME"
    android:id="@+id/text" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/left"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:maxHeight="30dp"
    android:maxWidth="30dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main Activity:**

```
...
<include layout="@layout/settings_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/accountStaticUnderline"
    android:id="@+id/termBegin"
    android:text="TEST" /> //DOESNT WORK
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the text that way won't work because `android:text` is not applicable to the `<include>` tag. More specifically, it's not applicable to the thing being included, which is a `RelativeLayout`. (You couldn't put the `android:text` on the `RelativeLayout` and have it apply to the `TextView`, nor would you expect that to work.)

My first suggestion (and the easiest immediate solution) is to use `TextView`'s built in support for compound drawables so you can simply use `TextView`s instead of `include`s and have a style resource for the attributes you want.

If that's not good enough for your use case, then you might need to make a custom View. This view will replace the `RelativeLayout` and have the `TextView` and `ImageView` as children. The main thing to decide is where and how the children are created and their references are obtained: you can create them manually in Java when the parent is being constructed; or you can use some combination of layouts with `<include>`s and/or `<merge>`s. Making the text attribute work then requires some use of a `<declare-styleable>`.

I assume you want the children to always appear the same and that you want to reuse the layout you already made (i.e. you don't want to set all the attributes manually), so this is what I would probably do:

```
public class MyButton extends RelativeLayout {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_button, this, true); // used with merge tag
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.text};
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyleAttributes(attributeSet, attrs);
        String text = a.getString(0, null);
        mTextView.setText(text);
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

In `res/layout/my_button.xml`:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="CHANGE ME"
        android:id="@+id/text" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/left"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:maxHeight="30dp"
        android:maxWidth="30dp"/>
</merge>
```

In your activity layout:

```
...
<!-- no more include -->
<com.package.MyButton
    android:id="@+id/something"
    android:layout_width="..."
    android:layout_height="..."
    android:text="..." />

<!-- you can have multiple instances with different IDs -->
<com.package.MyButton
    android:id="@+id/something_else"
    android:layout_width="..."
    android:layout_height="..."
    android:text="..." />
...
```

You could also use your own `<declare-styleable>` for the custom view, which will be necessary if later you want to have custom XML attributes for it, but the approach above should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

sure, just type this code in your activity

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("enter_text_here");
```

Comment: When I have multiple instances of this layout in one activity, how do I distinguish between them?

Comment: looks like bad practice, adding several same layouts in one activity. Try something else. For example, add buttons programmaticaly and keep them in array.
You better describe a task which you wanna complete by adding several layouts, maybe somebody gives you advice how to deal with it correct

Comment: Its meant to be a custom view. If we can use `<Button` multiple times on one activity, why is what I'm doing bad practice? Is there a better way to use my custom layout as a custom view?

Comment: You can use ListView or better RecyclerView and handle clicks in viewHolders